# Newbie: URL doesn't match django template name

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm working on my first django application, and I can't find anything in the docs that explains this.

I have a view called submit_proposal. If successful, it stores the relevant objects to the database then sends a user to a listing of all their open proposals. It displays correctly, but the listing page URL isn't shown by the browser.

Here's the code:

```
context = RequestContext(request,
                         dict(user_name=gc_user.get_full_name,
                              game_list=game_list,
                              POSTData=request.POST,
                         )
)
template = loader.get_template('user_proposals.html')
return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

This is called from submit_proposal, which passes the returned HttpResponse object back in turn:

```
result = user_proposals(request)
return result
```

I've looked at result in the debugger, and as far as I can tell it doesn't include a URL generated from the template name. Should I be doing something else to create the response? Or do I need to use something other than HttpResponse?

Thanks for your help!

Beverly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common way to do this in Django is to have two urls, for instance:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^proposal/$', 'app.views.submit_proposal', name='submit_proposal'),
    url(r'^proposal/all/$', 'app.views.list_proposals', name='list_proposals'),
```

Then the `submit_proposal` function should validate, store and redirect the user to `list_proposals` if successful

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def submit_proposal(request):
    ...
    return redirect('list_proposals')
```

The argument to redirect is the name of the url for listing proposals.

Comment: How do I get the context to the template this way? I tried
    redirect('user_proposals', context=context)
but I got "NoReverseMatch at /submit_proposal"

Comment: Ideally, you'd not need to pass the context since you have already saved the object into the database. You will pull the necessary context  from the database and from request in the list_proposal function itself.

Comment: Ah, so the list view gets called as though directly from the browser. I get it now, and it's working properly. Thanks!